# "A book to be read" vs "a book to read"

Tags: grammar, verbs, be

Which is grammatically correct: "a book to be read" or "a book to read"?
And what is the difference?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! What has your own research shown you? What makes you believe one is grammatically correct and the other isn't? Where have you looked to try to find an answer for your question before asking here? These are all vital bits of information that you should edit your post to include, so that people don't write answers that do not help you because you've already found the same elsewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be clicked over to ELL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both correct. *A book to be read* refers to a book that someone has decided will be read. For example, if there is a textbook that everyone taking a certain course is required to read, the course instructor might say

> This is a book to be read by everybody taking this course!

Someone who has a favourite book might say something like

> *Siddhartha* is certainly a book to be read!

to indicate that they think it's a book that people *should* read.

*A book to read* refers to a book which is available to read, but can sometimes imply that one is expected to read it. For an example of the former usage,

> I had to wait for an hour; I was glad I had a book to read!

One further demonstration of the difference:

> My teacher gave me a book to read on the train.

suggests that my teacher thought I might be bored on the train, so they gave me a book to read. (However, you could read it as implying that the teacher gave me a book which they expect me to read on the train!)

On the other hand,

> My teacher gave me a book to be read on the train.

is less ambiguous: the teacher definitely expects me to read the book on the train.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have nailed it on the head. :) Sorry I haven't provided any context to my questions; they were from the top of my head.